# How does `stty -echo; cat -v; stty echo` work to echo special keys?

Tags: bash, command-line, stty

`stty -echo; cat -v; stty echo` is a technique to see what key you send to terminal. But I just wonder how this command work? When I remove `stty -echo` it will print twice what you typed in. I know `stty -echo` is disabling terminal printing you type. More specifically, my quest is **"why can I use ';' connect commands to achieving disabling echo first then opening after cat -v command?" or Is there any correlation with ";" at all?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`;` just separates commands so they are run one after the other.

Here, if you enter that at the prompt of an interactive shell, the terminal device local echo will have been disabled and reenabled by the time you you get back to the prompt as long as you exit `cat` normally (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice, or on an empty line).

If `cat` is interrupted with SIGINT or SIGQUIT (if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>), shells like `bash` cancel the whole command line, so the `stty echo` command will *not* be run, and the local echo won't be reenabled.

In the `zsh` shell, you could do instead:

```
STTY=-echo cat -vt
```

Which is special syntax to change some tty settings only for the duration of a command. That way, the tty settings will be restored even if `cat` is interrupted.

Though `zsh` always restores the tty local echo by itself anyway.

In `bash`, you could do something similar with a helper function:

```
with_different_tty_settings() (
  tty_settings=$(stty -g) # save current settings
  trap 'stty "$tty_settings"' INT EXIT QUIT
  set -o noglob
  local IFS
  stty $STTY # split $STTY on default IFS characters
  "$@"
)
```

And call `cat` as:

```
STTY=-echo with_different_tty_settings cat -vt
```

(contrary to `zsh`'s `STTY`, it doesn't handle job suspension (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for instance) though).

If you change it to `STTY='-echo -isig'`, you'll be able to see what character <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends.

With `STTY='raw -echo'`, you'd be able to see *all* characters (and unmodified by the tty line discipline, and as soon as you enter them), but then you wouldn't be able to terminate `cat`.

But you could do `STTY='raw -echo time 30 min 0'` for `cat` to exit after 3 seconds of inactivity.